# Local Maxima, global maxima

Tags: calculus

Let $f:\mathbb{R}^2 \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ be an twice continuously differentiable function. Assume that $f$ has only one stationary point $(x_0,y_0)$, which is a local maximum.

Now my question: Can I assume, that this is a global maximum? 
I now, that there is no other critical point, because we have that $\nabla f(x,y)=0$ if and only if $(x,y)=(x_0,y_0)$.
But I'm not sure because one could imagine, that the gradient vanishes not another time, but it could be, that it vanishes in each component at different points and so the function maybe can change the orientation of the gradient.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is an example from Stewart's Calculus which shows that it is not necessarily a global maximum:

Let $f(x,y)=3xe^y-x^3-e^{3y}$.

Then f has only one stationary point $(1,0)$ which corresponds to a local maximum, but it is not a global maximum since, for example, $\;f(1,0)=1 \text{ but  } \;f(-3,0)=17$.